# FMDB - Error calling sqlite3_step (21: out of memory) rs

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, fmdb

I had integrate FMDB library in my code, i try to load multiple query in single function but i have received some issue

```
* Error calling sqlite3_step (21: out of memory) rs 
* FMDB not open
* FMDB is in use
```

Is it possible to run multiple query in single function?, please let me know your comments.

Thanks in Advance

I tried this FYI:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getMyInfo
{
   NSMutableArray *contactList = [NSMutableArray array];

    if(![instance.database open])
    {
        DLog(@"Could not open DB");
        return nil;
    }
    **********  QUERY 1   **************
    FMResultSet *resultSet=[instance.database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM mycontacts WHERE cont_hidden = 0 and cont_recent_chat_time IS NOT NULL ORDER BY strftime(cont_recent_chat_time) DESC"];
    if(resultSet)
    {
        while([resultSet next])
        {
            @autoreleasepool
            {
                int type = [resultSet intForColumn:@"contact_type"];
                Contactbean *contactObj = [[Contactbean alloc]init];
                [contactObj setPhoneNo:[resultSet stringForColumn:@"cont_phonenumber"]];
```

**********  QUERY 2   **************

```
                FMResultSet *getCountResult=[instance.database executeQuery:@"SELECT count(kchatid) FROM mychat WHERE kisread = 0 and kchatnumber = ?",[resultSet stringForColumn:@"cont_phonenumber"]];
                if ([getCountResult next]) {
                    if([getCountResult intForColumnIndex:0] > 0)
                    {
                        [contactObj setCount:[getCountResult intForColumnIndex:0]];
                    }
                }
                [getCountResult close];
```

**********  QUERY 3   **************

```
                FMResultSet *getRecentResult=[instance.database executeQuery:@"SELECT * from mychat where kchatnumber =? AND kchattime =?",[resultSet stringForColumn:@"cont_phonenumber"],[resultSet stringForColumn:@"status"]];

                if([getRecentResult next])
                {
                    [contactObj setStatus:[getRecentResult intForColumn:@"status"]];
                }
                [getRecentResult close];

                // Adding contact to the list
                [contactList addObject:contactObj];
            }
        }
    }
    [resultSet close];
    [instance.database close];
    return contactList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are not opening and closing properly the database object, should be something like this:

```
NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"theDataBase.sqlite"];
    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [database open];//Open the database
    //Execute the update you want
    [database executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO some_table (something) values (?)", someValue];
    //Execute the consults you want
    FMResultSet *results   = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM some_table"];
        if ([results next])
        {
            //Do something with the data it brings you
        }
    [database close];//Close the database
```

Dont forget to read the official documentation:
[FMDB v2.5](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)